# Is there any substantive difference between declaring a class normally versus in a package object?

Tags: scala

If I have a package `com.example`, I can create a class in that package like this:

```
package com.example {
  class MyClass
}
```

or like this:

```
package com {
  package object example {
    class MyClass
  }
}
```

In both cases, the resulting class is (as far as other Scala code is concerned, at least) `com.example.MyClass`.

There are certainly incidental differences. In the first instance, the resulting compiled class is `com/example/MyClass.class` whereas in the second it's `com/example/package$MyClass.class` but are there any substantive differences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference in generated class file names was discussed on [scala-internals](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/10482), and hopefully will disappear in Scala 2.10.

Comment: So, for completeness, the answer to the question "is there any substantive difference..." is "no"? Just accidental differences that will go away in 2.10? Thanks!

Comment: Correct. (There may be more bugs lurking, of course.)Package objects is a feature that may evolve further: see the "What's to Come" section here: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects.html

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of is that instead of being able to put only `class`es, `object`s or `type`s in a *package*, you can put `def`s, `val`s and `var`s in an *object*.

Comment: Yes - I'm aware that that's the point of a package object. But that's not the question I'm asking. The question is, if I put a class in a package object is that different in any substantive way from defining it normally.